# Use External ASP.NET Web API in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

I need to know how to use an external (with its own domain and everything) ASP.NET Web API RESTful web service in my MVC project. I know there's an easy way to do it in Javascript, but I need to be able to do it on the C# side. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure  use an HttpClient

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = client.GetAsync("{url}").Result;
    return result.Content.ReadAsAsync<{Type}>().Result
}
```

So I will be the first to admit this example is quick and dirty, but it gets the point across.  best practice would be to check for an error code in the result before reading the content, but without specific code to model after here I am really not entirely sure what you are after

Comment: I have that going currently, and it seems to work fine, but I can't seem to access it from another solution. Do you know if there's a way to access my web API from my MVC solution without launching the Web API to the internet?

Comment: the point of web api is to be decoupled from the mvc solution, so don't do that. You do need to have the api exposed on a webserver somewhere.(local IIS is fine for testing purposed)  then you can call the api using the code above